# get subversion logs by date

Tags: svn, version-control, versioning

How can I get svn logs by date?

I tried doing

```
svn log -vr {2010-11-14}:{2010-11-15}
```

but it only returns me 1 entry back which is commited on nov 12.

Answer (score 2):

Leaving out time information, your log command will only show changes that took place on november 14. The following excerpt from the documentation covers this issue:

```
svn log -r {2010-11-28}
```

> If you give a date without a
>   timestamp, such as 2010-11-28,
>   Subversion assumes a time of 00:00:00,
>   so looking for the most recent
>   revision won't return anything on the
>   28th.
>
> If you want to include the 28th in
>   your search, you can either specify
>   the 28th with the time ({"2010-11-28
>   23:59"}), or just specify the next day
>   ({2010-11-29}).